# MPMoviePlayerController memory management

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

My iPad app has a main view controller that contains a `MPMoviePlayerController` instance variable. The actual view contains a number of numbered buttons, and when each button is pressed, I change the `contentURL` property of the `MPMoviePlayerController` to load the corresponding movie file. This works very well, but I get a memory warning. Do I need to release the previous movie file before I change the `contentURL`? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController has lot of leaks in the simulator. Deleak on device, maybe there are no leaks.